# How to print a turtle variable equivalent to item 0 in a list in Netlogo?

Tags: excel, list, output, netlogo

I am trying to export a `turtle variable value that is <= item 0` of a patch list. These are the values I am interested in recording, but I am having trouble getting the code right for that.

I've tried below:

```
file-print turtles with [turtlevariable <= item 0 patchlist]
```

I know that's not right as I am getting the number of turtles, and not the turtle variable value. I would like to run this model 1000 times and am unsure how to create code for a file that will be manageable to manipulate in Excel.

I'm pretty sure there is a simple answer, but I just can't figure it out! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple questions here.  You need to post each question separately.  I will take on the following: how can you get a list of values for `turtlevariable`, but only for the values that are `< item 0 patchlist`.

```
globals [patchlist]
turtles-own [tvar]
patches-own [pvar]

to test
  ca
  ask patches [set pvar random-float 1.0]
  set patchlist [pvar] of patches
  let _p00 item 0 patchlist ;;compute only once
  crt 100
  ask turtles [set tvar random-float 1.0]
  let _tset (turtles with [tvar < _p00])
  let _tvals [tvar] of _tset
  print _tvals
end
```

You can always `file-print` anything you can `print`, so now you need to decide how exactly you want to format this list.  This is a separate question.  If you want to save as `.csv`, that is a separate question.  (But you will find multiple questions on this site addressing that.)  If you want to create one output file for multiple replicates, that is a separate question.  (But see questions on this site about BehaviorSpace.)  Hth.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Any suggestions for how to pull only the first value from the _tvals list? Those are the numbers I am really interested in.

Comment: The first value, or the smallest value?
Also, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I'd like the first value? Still struggling to do this.

Comment: Change `print _tvals` to `print item 0 _tvals`.  (Am I getting at what you mean?)

Comment: I've tried that and it kept getting hung up... I think I've figured out why though. Thank you again for all your help!